# please explain this error log

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

i have domain in godaddy and i am trying to install a script in my dedicated server or trying to access my domain righttimematrimony.com  it is not loading and showing errors.  one time my website loaded and shown sci-bin folder, after upload the data into server and tried to access my url, but shown lot of errors. please somebody help me what to do now.

This is the data in error log found at Cpanel -> Error Log.

```
[Mon Dec 29 04:14:23 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:14:23 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:14:05 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:14:05 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:14:03 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:14:03 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:14:01 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:14:01 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:13:57 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:13:57 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:12:58 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:12:58 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:12:50 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:12:50 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:12:43 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:12:43 2014] [alert] [client 106.66.138.199] /home/right/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Dec 29 04:04:13 2014] [error] [client 106.66.138.199] File does not exist: /home/right/public_html/403.shtml, referer: http://righttimematrimony.com/
[Mon Dec 29 04:04:13 2014] [error] [client 106.66.138.199] attempt to invoke directory as script: /home/right/public_html/cgi-bin/, referer: http://righttimematrimony.com/
[Mon Dec 29 04:04:08 2014] [error] [client 106.66.138.199] File does not exist: /home/right/public_html/404.shtml
[Mon Dec 29 04:04:08 2014] [error] [client 106.66.138.199] File does not exist: /home/right/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Dec 29 04:04:00 2014] [error] [client 106.66.138.199] File does not exist: /home/right/public_html/404.shtml
[Mon Dec 29 04:04:00 2014] [error] [client 106.66.138.199] File does not exist: /home/right/public_html/favicon.ico
```

Comment: I have also same problem.I try to find all possible way but can't find any solution.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this link: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/invalid-command-php_value-perhaps-mis-spelled-defined-module-not-included-184931.html

> You are using suPHP, so you cannot use the following directives in .htaccess files: php_flag, php_admin_flag, php_value, php_admin_value. You also cannot use these directives in the httpd.conf file; they are only valid when DSO is used as the PHP handler.
>
> Instead, use a custom php.ini file. Copy /usr/local/lib/php.ini to the directory that requires custom PHP values, and customize the PHP values in the "local" php.ini file. Note that the values in custom php.ini files are not "inherited" to subdirectories. If you place a custom php.ini file in /home/someuser/public_html, its settings will not be inherited by /home/someuser/public_html/somesubdir. /home/someuser/public_html/somesubdir would need its own custom php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

You're not running PHP as an Apache module.

Comment: easydownlink.com  other website hosted in this same server its working well..    please tell me what i have to do to make my site work

Comment: this answer looks like comment. i'm sure someone with similar problem would appreciate some solution - on linux: `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`

Comment: You must have been downvoted for not explaining how to fix that. Thanks to ya'll, I realized that when I upgraded to PHP 7, I needed to also install libapache2-mod-php7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Miss Files From Root Directory http://righttimematrimony.com/
one of missed file is favicon.ico.

The 403 Forbidden error means that whatever resource or webpage you were trying to access is forbidden from being accessed.

Comment: easydownlink.com  other website hosted in this same server its working well..    please tell me what i have to do to make my site work

Answer (score 0):

I am using php7.3 and:

```
apt-get install php7.3-mbstring libapache2-mod-php7.3
```

solved the error:

> Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module
>   not included in the server configuration