# How to enable php display_error on in my cPanel

Tags: .htaccess

I went through whatever is there and it showed me to add these two lines in my `.htaccess` file.

```
php_flag display_errors on 
php_value error_reporting "E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE"
```

But then I get this error log message :

```
Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

There is a very popular question in stackoverflow : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)   but there also it has been answered considering that the user has a local server. Here I am writing the php scripts direclty on my hostgator cPanel and want to see the line number and other useful information for debugging, but still nothing useful I found.

And doing a bit more digging [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683366/please-explain-this-error-log) tells that I need to add my own php.ini file. But even when I added the php.ini file and added those two lines nothing is shown. So how can someone debug the php code if writing the script direcly on the cPanel ?