# Error in custom php.ini: "Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

Tags: php, cpanel, ini

I currently have dedicated server which runs WHM/cPanel.
I ran into as issue after uploading my project to my webroot.
The error:

```
Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

My question is:
Is there any way to run the custom `php.ini` to get my project running?
I tried to edit the php-70u (which I'm running on my server) to edit my custom `php.ini` file.
But that didn't work for some reason.  Could i get a helping hand?

And my .htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size 500M
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value max_execution_time 60000
```

My custom php.ini

```
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Data Handling ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; The separator used in PHP generated URLs to separate arguments.
; PHP's default setting is "&".
; http://php.net/arg-separator.output
; Example:
;arg_separator.output = "&amp;"

; List of separator(s) used by PHP to parse input URLs into variables.
; PHP's default setting is "&".
; NOTE: Every character in this directive is considered as separator!
; http://php.net/arg-separator.input
; Example:
;arg_separator.input = ";&"

; This directive determines which super global arrays are registered when PHP
; starts up. G,P,C,E & S are abbreviations for the following respective super
; globals: GET, POST, COOKIE, ENV and SERVER. There is a performance penalty
; paid for the registration of these arrays and because ENV is not as commonly
; used as the others, ENV is not recommended on productions servers. You
; can still get access to the environment variables through getenv() should you
; need to.
; Default Value: "EGPCS"
; Development Value: "GPCS"
; Production Value: "GPCS";
; http://php.net/variables-order
variables_order = "GPCS"

; This directive determines which super global data (G,P,C,E & S) should
; be registered into the super global array REQUEST. If so, it also determines
; the order in which that data is registered. The values for this directive are
; specified in the same manner as the variables_order directive, EXCEPT one.
; Leaving this value empty will cause PHP to use the value set in the
; variables_order directive. It does not mean it will leave the super globals
; array REQUEST empty.
; Default Value: None
; Development Value: "GP"
; Production Value: "GP"
; http://php.net/request-order
request_order = "GP"

; This directive determines whether PHP registers $argv & $argc each time it
; runs. $argv contains an array of all the arguments passed to PHP when a script
; is invoked. $argc contains an integer representing the number of arguments
; that were passed when the script was invoked. These arrays are extremely
; useful when running scripts from the command line. When this directive is
; enabled, registering these variables consumes CPU cycles and memory each time
; a script is executed. For performance reasons, this feature should be disabled
; on production servers.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to On for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/register-argc-argv
register_argc_argv = Off

; When enabled, the ENV, REQUEST and SERVER variables are created when they're
; first used (Just In Time) instead of when the script starts. If these
; variables are not used within a script, having this directive on will result
; in a performance gain. The PHP directive register_argc_argv must be disabled
; for this directive to have any affect.
; http://php.net/auto-globals-jit
auto_globals_jit = On

; Whether PHP will read the POST data.
; This option is enabled by default.
; Most likely, you won't want to disable this option globally. It causes $_POST
; and $_FILES to always be empty; the only way you will be able to read the
; POST data will be through the php://input stream wrapper. This can be useful
; to proxy requests or to process the POST data in a memory efficient fashion.
; http://php.net/enable-post-data-reading
;enable_post_data_reading = Off

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 2G

; Automatically add files before PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-prepend-file
auto_prepend_file =

; Automatically add files after PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-append-file
auto_append_file =

; By default, PHP will output a character encoding using
; the Content-type: header.  To disable sending of the charset, simply
; set it to be empty.
;
; PHP's built-in default is text/html
; http://php.net/default-mimetype
default_mimetype = "text/html"

; PHP's default character set is set to empty.
; http://php.net/default-charset
;default_charset = "UTF-8"

; Always populate the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA variable. PHP's default behavior is
; to disable this feature. If post reading is disabled through
; enable_post_data_reading, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is *NOT* populated.
; http://php.net/always-populate-raw-post-data
;always_populate_raw_post_data = On

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path

; The root of the PHP pages, used only if nonempty.
; if PHP was not compiled with FORCE_REDIRECT, you SHOULD set doc_root
; if you are running php as a CGI under any web server (other than IIS)
; see documentation for security issues.  The alternate is to use the
; cgi.force_redirect configuration below
; http://php.net/doc-root
doc_root =

; The directory under which PHP opens the script using /~username used only
; if nonempty.
; http://php.net/user-dir
user_dir =

; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir=/opt/php/php-5.5.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
; On windows:
; extension_dir=/opt/php/php-5.5.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212

; Directory where the temporary files should be placed.
; Defaults to the system default (see sys_get_temp_dir)
; sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"

; Whether or not to enable the dl() function.  The dl() function does NOT work
; properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically
; disabled on them.
; http://php.net/enable-dl
enable_dl = Off

; cgi.force_redirect is necessary to provide security running PHP as a CGI under
; most web servers.  Left undefined, PHP turns this on by default.  You can
; turn it off here AT YOUR OWN RISK
; **You CAN safely turn this off for IIS, in fact, you MUST.**
; http://php.net/cgi.force-redirect
;cgi.force_redirect = 1

; if cgi.nph is enabled it will force cgi to always sent Status: 200 with
; every request. PHP's default behavior is to disable this feature.
;cgi.nph = 1

; if cgi.force_redirect is turned on, and you are not running under Apache or Netscape
; (iPlanet) web servers, you MAY need to set an environment variable name that PHP
; will look for to know it is OK to continue execution.  Setting this variable MAY
; cause security issues, KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING FIRST.
; http://php.net/cgi.redirect-status-env
;cgi.redirect_status_env = 

; cgi.fix_pathinfo provides *real* PATH_INFO/PATH_TRANSLATED support for CGI.  PHP's
; previous behaviour was to set PATH_TRANSLATED to SCRIPT_FILENAME, and to not grok
; what PATH_INFO is.  For more information on PATH_INFO, see the cgi specs.  Setting
; this to 1 will cause PHP CGI to fix its paths to conform to the spec.  A setting
; of zero causes PHP to behave as before.  Default is 1.  You should fix your scripts
; to use SCRIPT_FILENAME rather than PATH_TRANSLATED.
; http://php.net/cgi.fix-pathinfo
;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

; FastCGI under IIS (on WINNT based OS) supports the ability to impersonate
; security tokens of the calling client.  This allows IIS to define the
; security context that the request runs under.  mod_fastcgi under Apache
; does not currently support this feature (03/17/2002)
; Set to 1 if running under IIS.  Default is zero.
; http://php.net/fastcgi.impersonate
;fastcgi.impersonate = 1

; Disable logging through FastCGI connection. PHP's default behavior is to enable
; this feature.
;fastcgi.logging = 0

; cgi.rfc2616_headers configuration option tells PHP what type of headers to
; use when sending HTTP response code. If it's set 0 PHP sends Status: header that
; is supported by Apache. When this option is set to 1 PHP will send
; RFC2616 compliant header.
; Default is zero.
; http://php.net/cgi.rfc2616-headers
;cgi.rfc2616_headers = 0

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2G

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Fopen wrappers ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On

date.timezone =  "Europe/Paris"

; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = On

; Define the anonymous ftp password (your email address). PHP's default setting
; for this is empty.
; http://php.net/from
;from="john@doe.com"

; Define the User-Agent string. PHP's default setting for this is empty.
; http://php.net/user-agent
;user_agent="PHP"

; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
; http://php.net/default-socket-timeout
default_socket_timeout = 60

; If your scripts have to deal with files from Macintosh systems,
; or you are running on a Mac and need to deal with files from
; unix or win32 systems, setting this flag will cause PHP to
; automatically detect the EOL character in those files so that
; fgets() and file() will work regardless of the source of the file.
; http://php.net/auto-detect-line-endings
;auto_detect_line_endings = Off
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is there any way you can pare down the code to show us only the useful bits to this issue.  Alternatively, is there anything you think it might be related to - anything you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27683366/5411817 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **MultiPHP Editor** from WHM. You can define a custom php version for each of your cPanel accounts. Then from the cPanel web interface of your account you can edit/adjust your php settings accordingly. *Just search for PHP in cPanel*. These settings should be performed using the cPanel/WHM interface and not by manually editing the files on your server. Manually edited files (via ssh/ftp etc) will be overwritten anyway when you do a change via cPanel or WHM.